# C# Convert C# 6.0 to C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert this C# 6.0 code to C# 4.0?

```
public void Subscribe(string message, Action<IMessagingService> callback) =>
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessagingService>(this, message, callback);
```

or

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture) => null;
```

Can I simply create get property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression-bodied method you've shown is just C#6 shorthand for:

```
public void Subscribe(string message, Action<IMessagingService> callback)
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MessagingService>(this, message, callback);
}
```

Comment: oh so easy. And for second one is then just public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { null; } ?

Comment: @mbrc equivalent to the second one is just method returning null.

Comment: @mbrc yes, it is. Have a look to [C#6 features description](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), it may be useful to you.